# MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 3

Tags: mysql, database, mysql-error-1064

I have some problem in PHPMyadmin when I import my DB.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `wp_cf_forms` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `form_id` varchar(18) COLLATE utf8_general_ci; NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `type` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_general_ci; NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `config` longtext COLLATE utf8_general_ci; NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `form_id` (`form_id`)
)
```

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 3(`form_id` varchar(18) COLLATE utf8_general_ci; NOT NULL DEFAULT '',)

Has anyone any idea how I can solve this?

Comment: Hi Thorsten CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `wp_cf_forms` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `form_id` varchar(18) COLLATE utf8_general_ci; NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `type` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_general_ci; NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `config` longtext COLLATE utf8_general_ci; NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `form_id` (`form_id`)
) This is my script. Sql has simply output there because error

Comment: I suppose that the semicolons at `utf8_general_ci;` are getting in the way. (And if I am not mistaken, it's rather uncommon to set the collation at column level anyway. You can set it at table or even at database level instead.)

Comment: And according to the docs (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table.html) the `COLLATE` clause comes after `[NOT] NULL` and `DEFAULT`.

Comment: On a side note: A column called `form_id` should either be a foreign key to some forms table or be the primary key if this is the forms table itself.

Answer (score 0):

from what said @Thorsten Kettner you can solve this problem doing

```
CREATE DATABASE mydatabase CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;

USE mydatabase;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `wp_cf_forms` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `form_id` varchar(18) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `type` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `config` longtext NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `form_id` (`form_id`)
);
```

the result

```
mysql> CREATE DATABASE mydatabase CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.02 sec)

mysql> USE mydatabase;
Database changed
mysql> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `wp_cf_forms` (
    ->   `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    ->   `form_id` varchar(18) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    ->   `type` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    ->   `config` longtext NOT NULL,
    ->   PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    ->   KEY `form_id` (`form_id`)
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.03 sec)

mysql> SHOW TABLES ;
+----------------------+
| Tables_in_mydatabase |
+----------------------+
| wp_cf_forms          |
+----------------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)

mysql>
```